# finding if patient followed up with doctor after 90 days using DataAdd function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table that has 2 datasets, one dataset has the doctor office data and the other one has the hospital data.  So what i am trying to find out is if patient has followed up with his doctor after 90 days from his initial admission at the hospital.  Patient can have multiple admission dates and we look at each admission separately if they followed up with their doctor after 90 days.  The calculation should be

```
 if service_date - discharge_Date > 90 then flag as 1



SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @TEST TABLE
(
     [NAME] VARCHAR(15)
    ,[SERVICE_DT] DATETIME
    ,[DSCH_DT] DATETIME
    ,[SRC] VARCHAR(50)
    ,[LOC] VARCHAR(50)
)



INSERT INTO @TEST ([NAME], [SERVICE_DT], [DSCH_DT], [SRC], [LOC])
VALUES ('MIKE', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-01', 'Hospital', 'NY')
      ,('MIKE', '2014-2-27',  '2014-02-28', 'Hospital', 'NY')
      ,('MIKE', '2014-07-15',  '2014-07-15', 'Hospital', 'NY')
      ,('DAVID', '2014-09-04',  '2014-09-04', 'Hospital', 'NY')
      ,('DAVID', '2014-04-01',  '2014-04-02', 'Hospital', 'NY')       
      ,('TOM', '2014-05-01',  '2014-08-15', 'Hospital', 'TX')

      ,('MIKE', '2014-03-02', '9999-01-01', 'Doctor_Offfice', 'NY' )
      ,('MIKE', '2014-05-22', '9999-01-01', 'Doctor_Offfice', 'NY' )
      ,('DAVID', '2014-01-01',  '9999-01-01', 'Doctor_Offfice', 'NY')
      ,('DAVID', '2014-05-03', '9999-01-01', 'Doctor_Offfice', 'NY')
      ,('TOM', '2014-08-20',  '9999-01-01', 'Doctor_Offfice', 'TX')
      ,('DAVID', '2014-12-02', '9999-01-01', 'Doctor_Offfice', 'NY')



;WITH MYTEST ([NAME], [SERVICE_DT], [DSCH_DT], [SRC], [LOC])  AS
(
    SELECT NAME
          ,[SERVICE_DT]
          ,[DSCH_DT]
          ,[SRC]
          ,LOC

    FROM @TEST
)
,HOSP AS
(
SELECT NAME
          --,[SERVICE_DT]
          ,[DSCH_DT]
          ,[LOC] FROM MYTEST
          WHERE SRC = 'Hospital'
 )
 ,DOC AS
(
SELECT NAME
          ,[SERVICE_DT]
          --,[DSCH_DT]
          ,[SRC] FROM MYTEST
          WHERE SRC = 'Doctor_Offfice'
 )  

  SELECT HOSP.NAME, HOSP.DSCH_DT, DOC.SERVICE_DT, HOSP.LOC AS HOSP_SRC, DOC.SRC AS DOC_SRC, CASE 
   WHEN HOSP.DSCH_DT < DateAdd(d, 90, DOC.SERVICE_DT) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FU90 FROM HOSP INNER 
   JOIN DOC ON HOSP.NAME = DOC.NAME   

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Comment: I work at a hospital and part of what you are attempting doesn't make sense.  You are looking for followup visits within 90 days of an admission.  Given that hospital visits can last more than one day, shouldn't you be looking for followup visits within 90 days of a discharge?

Comment: yes, it should be from the discharge date.

Comment: I'll give you a hint.  The datediff function is more appropriate to what you are attempting than is dateadd.

Comment: IN Mike's case... How do you want to handle the situation where was in the hospital twice in a short period but did follow-up with the dr once.  And it was within 90 days of BOTH hospital visits?  How do you know the patient didn't discuss with the DR BOTH Visits to the hospital in the 90 day window.. So I guess I'm questionoing your expected results why is Mike a 0 and for that matter. why do you have any 0's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Original Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/531c02/14/0) is close.

This technically meets all the provided requirements, but doesn't match your desired results.
So either the requirements are incorrect (or missing some), or your expected results are.

Specifically, I'm not sure how to account for two hospital visits and a dr visit within 90 days of both...

What this does:

1. It splits the data into two sets. One for Dr office and one for Hospital. (you did this with CTE fine)
2. It then joins these sets based on patient name and and having a dr visit within 90 days of discharge.
3. it then evaluates if the dr.location is null (could evaluate any value really) but if it is, tat means they didn't follow-up due to the left joint his works.

.

```
SELECT  H.name, H.service_Dt, H.DSCH_DT, H.src, H.loc, 
CASE WHEN DR.LOC is not null then 1 else 0 end as FollowUp90
FROM test H
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, service_Dt, DSCH_DT, src, loc 
           FROM TEST 
           WHERE SRC = 'Doctor_Offfice') DR
  ON DR.Name = H.Name
 and DR.Service_DT between H.DSCH_DT and DATEADD(DAY,  90, H.DSCH_DT)
WHERE H.Src = 'Hospital'
GROUP BY H.name, H.service_Dt, H.DSCH_DT, H.src, H.loc, 
CASE WHEN DR.LOC is not null then 1 else 0 end
Order by H.Name, H.Service_DT
```

As close as I'm going to get without further requirement definition or explanation of why your expected results are the way they are.  They don't conform to your stated requirements.

--- Edit after accepted:
To account for the first occurrence, we just need to min the service date on the subselect and add a group by.

However, if someone followed up with two different doctors on the same date, this will still result in two entries being found.

```
SELECT  H.name, H.service_Dt, H.DSCH_DT, H.src, H.loc, 
CASE WHEN DR.LOC is not null then 1 else 0 end as FollowUp90
FROM test H
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, min(service_Dt) Service_DT, loc, src
           FROM TEST 
           WHERE SRC = 'Doctor_Offfice'
           GROUP BY name, loc,src  ) DR
  ON DR.Name = H.Name
 and DR.Service_DT between H.DSCH_DT and DATEADD(DAY,  90, H.DSCH_DT)
WHERE H.Src = 'Hospital'
GROUP BY H.name, H.service_Dt, H.DSCH_DT, H.src, H.loc, 
CASE WHEN DR.LOC is not null then 1 else 0 end
Order by H.Name, H.Service_DT
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/531c02/25/0)

Comment: thanks, if Mike went to hospital 2 or 3 different dates, we always look at the discharge date for each admission and compare that to the service date at the doctor office. If there are 3 admission for Mike at the hospital and only one doctor visit but and it meets the 90 day requirement then we say Mike had 3 follow up. hope i explained little bit better

Comment: modified above fiddle to [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba397/13) . same question, though, what if there's 2 dr visits (3/2 and 5/22) after Mike's 2/27/14 hospital admission?

Comment: Mike was discharged on 1/1/2014 and 2/28/2014. a dr's visit on 3/2 is within 90 days of both.  Did the one dr's visit meet the 90 day requirement for both? If yes, then the above SQL and fiddle meet your needs.  If it doesn't help me understand why. as I believe it does.

Comment: thank you so much, this works great but one issue here i see is that same discharge can have only one follow-up visit and normally we go with the most recent date.  example, 2/28 discharge meets the 90 requirement for 2 follow up visits 3/2 and 5/22 but we only display the one most recent which is 3/2. i don't want to count 2 follow ups for the same discharge. thanks man i really appreciate your help.  i will close it once you adjust this.

Comment: @moe added an edit to account for this occurrence, however this will still present a problem if the "name" visited two doctors on the same data at different locations.  Hopefully not a frequent occurrence, but one that could happen nevertheless.